# 2016 Ford Explorer headlights

Tags: headlight

2016 Ford Explorer left front headlight is out and the right will not turn off at all. It stayed on all night. Checked the fuses and they appear fine. Any ideas? I’m thinking it must be electrical

Comment: Are you saying the headlight was on even with the ignition off, key out, etc?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair. And are you sure that the light selector was in the off or auto position at the end of the day?

Comment: Yes we have to disconnect the battery to shut it off.